# Passing data from MVC Controller to PartialView using MVC unobtrusive Ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to pass a count value from an ASP.NET MVC ActionLink to a PartialView. The first time i want it to load 9 stories. The second time the user clicks the button it loads 6 more stories and so on. I am using MVC Unobtrusive ajax to load stories asynchronously but not sure how to pass the count value.I just set it to grab 1.

**View**

```
@model Models.HomePageModel


@{
   AjaxOptions ajaxOpts = new AjaxOptions
   {
    UpdateTargetId = "tableBody"
   };
}

<div id="tableBody">
  @Html.Action("GetArticleData")
</div>

@using(Ajax.BeginForm("GetArticleData", ajaxOpts))
{
     <div class="headlines-show-more">
     <button type="submit">Show More News</button>
     </div>
 }
```

**Controller for PartialViewResult**

```
 public PartialViewResult GetArticleData()
    {
        HomePageModel model = new HomePageModel();
        model.GetDetails();

        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

**PartialResult View**

```
 @model Models.HomePageModel
 @foreach (var item in Model.HeadlinesNews.Skip(0).Take(1))    
 {
 <a>
    <span>
        <span>@item.Category</span>
            <span></span>
            <p>@item.NewsTitle</p>
        </span>
    </span></a>
   }
```

Comment: How are you determining how many to return each time? 9 the 1st time, 6 the 2nd time, how many the 3rd, 4th, etc times?

Comment: 6 more the third, 6 more the fourth, everytime the button is pressed its 6 more

Comment: Start by changing your method to `public PartialViewResult GetArticleData(int startAt, int count)` and use `.Skip(startAt).Take(count)` which should be done in the method, not the view! Then you will need hidden inputs for `startAt` and `count` which can initially be `0` and `9`. Then in the `AjaxOptions.OnSuccess` function, update the values of the hidden fields.